# How do add initial number?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

```
def find_least_numbers_to_exceed_target(numbers, target):
    dp = [float('inf')] * (target + 1)
    dp[0] = 0    
    for num in numbers:
        for i in range(target, num - 1, -1):
            dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i - num] + 1)

    return dp[target]

numbers = [4, 3, 4, 1, 2]
target = 10
result = find_least_numbers_to_exceed_target(numbers, target)
print(f"The least number of elements needed to achieve {target} or exceed it is {result}")
```

The code above is finding the least number to achieve or exceed the target number. But I am stuck on how to add an initial number. For example, I set the initial number to 3, so I need two more numbers which are 4 and 4 to achieve 10.

My question is: How do set an initial number?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just call your function on 10 - 3 rather than 10

Comment: This should be easy. `Hint: Subtract initial from target before executing find_least_numbers_to_exceed_target`

Comment: Can you tell us your expected output? Your _initial number_ is confusing.

Comment: [Stack Overflow homework FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)